# Run Ansible Task in localhost instead of inventory host

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I need to check one file (/tmp/test.html) exist on localhost and if it exist execute the other tasks.
Can you please help to run this first task (name: Check exist and copy) in localhost(workstation).

localhost: workstation
remotehost: servera,serverb

Below is my playbook.yml

```
---
- name: Check exist and copy
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: check if file is exists #need to execute this task in workstation
    stat: 
     path: /tmp/test.html
    register: file_present

  - name: copy to taggroup 1
    copy: 
     src: /tmp/test.html 
     dest: /tmp/dest1.html
    when: file_present.stat.exists == 0 and inventory_hostname in groups ['taggroup1']

  - name: copy to taggroup 2
    copy: 
     src: /tmp/test.html 
     dest: /tmp/dest2.html
    when: file_present.stat.exists == 0 and inventory_hostname in groups ['taggroup2']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q: *"Check file **/tmp/test.html** exists on localhost."*

A: Module ***stat*** is not needed when [paths are tested at localhost](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-paths). For example, the play will fail if the file */tmp/test.html* does not exist, and continue the play otherwise

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    my_file: /tmp/test.html

  tasks:

    - fail:
        msg: "[ERROR] {{ my_file }} does not exist."
      when: my_file is not exists
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: Continue play.
      run_once: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
---
- name: Check exist and copy
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: check if file is exists #need to execute this task in workstation
    stat: 
     path: /tmp/test.html
    register: file_present
    delegate_to: localhost

  - name: copy to taggroup 1
    copy: 
     src: /tmp/test.html 
     dest: /tmp/dest1.html
    when: file_present.stat.exists and inventory_hostname in groups ['taggroup1']

  - name: copy to taggroup 2
    copy: 
     src: /tmp/test.html 
     dest: /tmp/dest2.html
    when: file_present.stat.exists and inventory_hostname in groups ['taggroup2']
```

See [the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation).

You can use `delegate_to:` to run a task on a different machine than the current `ansible_host`.

Comment: Note that with the above playbook, the delegated task will run for every host in the `all` group (e.g. if you have 100 hosts, it will run 100 times). You might want to have a look at [`run_once`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once) and [`deletegate_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegated-facts) so that you run it a single time and store facts for localhost. Your test in `when` clause would then become: `hostvars['localhost'].file_present.stat.exists`

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
---

- name: Check exist and copy
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: check if file is exists #need to execute this task in workstation
      stat: path=/tmp/test.html
    register: file_present
    delegate_to: localhost 

  - name: copy to taggroup 1
    copy: 
     src: /tmp/test.html 
     dest: /tmp/dest1.html
    when: file_present.stat.exists and inventory_hostname in groups ['taggroup1']

  - name: copy to taggroup 2
    copy: 
     src: /tmp/test.html 
     dest: /tmp/dest2.html
    when: file_present.stat.exists and inventory_hostname in groups ['taggroup2']
```

Comment: What is the difference with the answer from Calum Halpin which was posted 1h before yours ? This looks like an absolute duplicate to me...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the great support. This is the fixed answer.

```
---
- name: Check exist and copy
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: check if file is exists #need to execute this task in workstation
    stat: 
     path: /tmp/test.html
    register: file_present
    delegate_to: localhost
    run_once_ true

  - name: copy to taggroup 1
    copy: 
     src: /tmp/test.html 
     dest: /tmp/dest1.html
    when: file_present.stat.exists and inventory_hostname in groups ['taggroup1']

  - name: copy to taggroup 2
    copy: 
     src: /tmp/test.html 
     dest: /tmp/dest2.html
    when: file_present.stat.exists and inventory_hostname in groups ['taggroup2']
```